# Bauerca drag-sort-listview issue, entire list item is the handle

Tags: android-listview

I've been using Bauerca's drag-sort-listview, it's easy enough to setup and use, but I'm having an issue where the entire list item is the handle instead of just the drawable I set as the handle. Here's the appropriate XML:

```
    <com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
        xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk**/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/paletteView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        dslv:drag_handle_id="@id/dragHandle"
        dslv:sort_enabled="true"
        dslv:remove_enabled="false"
        dslv:drag_start_mode="onDrag" />
```

And here's the XML for the list item layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- Color View has to be set to specific width/height or else it won't show at all  -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/paletteItemText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/dragHandle"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
<View
    android:id="@+id/colorView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/paletteItemText" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@id/dragHandle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/drag_handle" />
```

Notice the ImageVIew has the id of dragHandle which is used by the drag-sort-listview, that id isn't used anywhere else.

The biggest problem with this is it's making it so I can't press or long press the list item anymore.

Comment: OK, so I just noticed something very strange, I can get rid of all the dslv lines in my XML, and it still makes the entire list item a handle, in otherwords all I have to do is declare a <com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView> and it will make all it's items dragable just by click on the item itself. This doesn't make any sense from all the examples I've looked up online, has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: I should also note I do have the latest version of the library, 0.6.1

Comment: Even if I set sort_enabled and drag_enabled to false, it still happens! This isn't making any sense, is this library not compatible with api version 19???

Answer (score 3):

AHAH!!! I figured it out, so the issue was actually quite simple, in the XML where I have this: xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk**/res-auto"
It should have been this: xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.torygaurnier.openpalette"

I'm new to android development, so I didn't realize this, com.torygaurnier.openpalette is my package name, so the namespace has to point to your own package name.